# Webpack -- web-server not compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Trying to get webpack set up so I can load in my different React components in an organized way, but for some reason I cannot get webpack-dev-server to load in my files correctly.

I'll make a change to a file and save it, and in the terminal I'll see it run a process ending with 'bundle is now VALID", but when I load the web page on my local server it doesn't actually update.

I have it running within a 'react_container_build' file, and in the terminal it tells me "webpack result is served from /react_container_build/" but again, nothing shows up.

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: What's your webpack.config look like?

Comment: Like lux said, we need to see your config.  My hunch is that you do not have a public path configured.